# Why input type="url" validation not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, input

I want that in the input field only url should allow so I tried to put type="url" in input tag but it is not working i can find out what preventing it to work.
More over if anyone help me to tell is their any way so that I can only allow .com suffix url in the input.

Please help me

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()  => {
  document.querySelector('button.test-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = '<h3>Please Wait...</h3>';
    setTimeout(yes, 7000)
  })
})

function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input type="url" id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<button class='test-btn'>Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: The validation is done by a form. There's no form in your markup, and therefor no validation. -> `<form validate><input type="url" name="url" /><button>Submit</button></form>`

Comment: On using form tag it showing the validation. But I want if the user not enter the correct types (here url) then button will not trigger. And might due to javascript code, alert is showing but at the same time button is trigger the call function which should be prevented

Comment: You have to adapt your script to work with a `<form>` (e.g. you now want the `submit` event of the form and not the `click` event of the button) but that's a question for your preferred search provider.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

I disabled the test button and enable it if the url is valid according the the HTML5 url rules

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {


  document.getElementById('url').addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      document.getElementById('test1').disabled = !e.target.checkValidity();
  })

  document.querySelector('button.test-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = '<h3>Please Wait...</h3>';

    setTimeout(yes, 7000)
  })
})

function yes() {

  var name = document.getElementById('fullName');
  var url = document.getElementById('url');


  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input type="text" id="fullName" />
</label>
<label>
    Your URL: 
    <input type="url" id="url" />
</label>
<br />
<button class='test-btn' id="test1" disabled>Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Ok, alert it is

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

document.querySelector('button.test-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  var url = document.getElementById('url');
  if (!url.value || !url.checkValidity()) {
    alert("Please enter valid URL");
    url.focus()
    return
  }

    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = '<h3>Please Wait...</h3>';

    setTimeout(yes, 7000)
  })
})

function yes() {

  var name = document.getElementById('fullName');


  // var loc = document.getElementById('loc'); // location is reserved, but you do not have a location field
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input type="text" id="fullName" />
</label>
<label>
    Your URL: 
    <input type="url" id="url" />
</label>
<br />
<button class='test-btn' id="test1">Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: @Ashish see second version

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', ()  => {
  document.querySelector('button.test-btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  if (name.endsWith('.com')){
    document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = '<h3>Please Wait...</h3>';
    setTimeout(yes, 7000);}
  })
})

function yes() {
  var button = document.getElementById('test');
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var age = document.getElementById('age');
  var location = document.getElementById('location');
  var str = 'Hello! <p> My name is Ashish</p><p>How Are You: ' + name.value +
    '';
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = str;
};
```

```html
<form>
<label>
    Your Name: 
    <input type="url" id="name" required />
</label>
<br />
<button class='test-btn'>Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you test your answer? I don't think this does what OP wants.